# How to make 'Loading' message disappear when an error occurs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When a user clicks the 'search' button, a 'Loading' message appears and that disappears when the results appear on the screen.

If geolocation fails, they are shown an alert, but the 'Loading' message stays on the screen. Obviously, I want the loading message to disappear when the geolocation fails.

I know I have to do a few things with the code, but I don't really know where to start. I thought it would simply be a case of adding a `.finally` function in the controller, but that doesn't work.

the geolocation factory:

```
beerStalker.factory('GeoLocation', function() {
  return {
    getLocation: function() {

      var deferred = $.Deferred();

      // if geo location is supported
      if(navigator.geolocation) {

        // get current position and pass the results to getPostalCode or time out after 5 seconds if it fails
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, this.geoLocationError, {
          timeout: 5000
        });

      } else {
        alert('Your browser does not support Geo Location.');
      }
      return deferred.promise();
    },

    geoLocationError: function() {
      alert('Geo Location failed.');
    }
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
beerStalker.controller('BeerStalkController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'ApiCall', 'GeoLocation', function($scope, $resource, ApiCall, GeoLocation) {

  $scope.autoSearch = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $.when(GeoLocation.getLocation()).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      return [data.coords.longitude, data.coords.latitude];
    }).then(function(location) {
      ApiCall.autoSearch(location[1], location[0]).then(function(results){
        $scope.searchResult = results
        $scope.loading = false;
      });
    }); 
  };

  $scope.customSearch = function() { 
    $scope.loading = true;
    ApiCall.customSearch($scope.cityName).then(function(results){
      $scope.searchResult = results
      $scope.loading = false;
    });
  };
}]);
```

PS it's built with Angular.
Github repo: https://github.com/Yorkshireman/beerstalker

Comment: `$resource` promise returns two arguments, `Success and failure`. You van make use of second argument.

Comment: i am just download and run it. i will works. if i am trying to search abc it will be not found so this code is work like display and and hide. so where is the problem?

Comment: "If geolocation fails, they are shown an alert, but the 'Loading' message stays on the screen. Obviously, I want the loading message to disappear when the geolocation fails."

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the main issue here is that you are not using deferred.reject basically in your GeoLocation factory, when the navigator.geolocation you should use:

```
} else {
    //alert('Your browser does not support Geo Location.');
    deferred.reject(response);
  }
```

After this you can easily add a simple .catch statement within your controller. This catch statement will submit the alert and then you can also set loading to false like this:

```
.then(function(location) {
  ApiCall.autoSearch(location[1], location[0]).then(function(results){
    $scope.searchResult = results
    $scope.loading = false;
  })
.catch(function(location){
    alert('Your browser does not support Geo Location.');
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

Hopefully this helps answer your question.

Comment: Catch only works if you're throwing an Error().  What he needs to handle a rejection is a second callback in his `then(function(success){}, function(failure){});`

Comment: the .catch is just a second way of writing exactly what you wrote there, though the confusion is easy to come across since catch is part of the error handling.

Comment: Ah, I'm used to other promise libraries that use catch only for thrown errors and expect you to provide a callback in then() to handle rejected promises.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution, because it only handles one error. There are two possible 'errors' - one is "Geo location failed" and the other is "Your browser does not support Geo Location"

Comment: Once the error is caught a simple if statement can get the error from the location parameter and display accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're leaving your promise un-resolved.  You need to reject the promise because it failed.  Like so.

```
beerStalker.factory('GeoLocation', function() {
  return {
    getLocation: function() {

      var deferred = $.Deferred();

      // if geo location is supported
      if(navigator.geolocation) {

        // get current position and pass the results to getPostalCode or time out after 5 seconds if it fails
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, this.geoLocationError, {
          timeout: 5000
        });

      } else {
        deffered.reject('Your browser does not support Geo Location.');
      }
      return deferred.promise();
    },

    geoLocationError: function() {
      alert('Geo Location failed.');
    }
  }
});
```

In a promise, a second callback for failure needs to be supplied in your then().  `then(function(success){}, function(failure){})`

```
beerStalker.controller('BeerStalkController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'ApiCall', 'GeoLocation', function($scope, $resource, ApiCall, GeoLocation) {

  $scope.autoSearch = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $.when(GeoLocation.getLocation()).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      return [data.coords.longitude, data.coords.latitude];
    }, function(failureReason){alert(failureReason);}).then(function(location) {
      ApiCall.autoSearch(location[1], location[0]).then(function(results){
        $scope.searchResult = results
        $scope.loading = false;
      });
    }).finally(function(){$scope.loading = false}); 
  };

  $scope.customSearch = function() { 
    $scope.loading = true;
    ApiCall.customSearch($scope.cityName).then(function(results){
      $scope.searchResult = results
      $scope.loading = false;
    });
  };
}]);
```

Notice that I moved the Alert to happen in the failure.  And I moved `$scope.loading=false;` to a finally statement to make sure it's executed every time regardless.

Comment: Getting `TypeError: GeoLocation.getLocation(...).then(...).then(...).finally is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.autoSearch (http://localhost:8080/js/beerStalkerController.js:15:15)` (which is the `.finally` line)

Comment: That error is pretty much telling you what's wrong.  It could be this line `$.when(GeoLocation.getLocation())`  I'm not sure why it's inside `$.when()`  maybe it should just be `GeoLocation.getLocation().then(...).finally(...)`.  Sorry for missing that the first time.

Comment: Hi Squeegy - I'm using it without `$when` - just `GeoLocation.getLocation()` etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to `resolve` or `reject` if you want the `finally` block to work. As [`$q.deferred` is an anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns), use [$q constructor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) - `$q(resolve, reject)` instead.

```
beerStalker.factory('GeoLocation', function () {
    return {
        getLocation : function () {
            return $(resolve, reject) {
                // if geo location is supported
                if (navigator.geolocation) {

                    // get current position and pass the results to getPostalCode or time out after 5 seconds if it fails
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, { // if it fails 'reject' will be called
                        timeout : 5000
                    });

                } else {
                    alert('Your browser does not support Geo Location.');
                    reject();
                }
            }
        },

        /** notify about the error in the controller
        geoLocationError : function () {
        alert('Geo Location failed.');
        }
         **/

    }
});

/** the GeoLocation.getLocation call in the controller **/
GeoLocation.getLocation().then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { // you don't need when because it's an angular $q promise
    return [data.coords.longitude, data.coords.latitude];
}).then(function (location) {
    return ApiCall.autoSearch(location[1], location[0]);
}).then(function (results) {
    $scope.searchResult = results;
}).catch(function (error) { // catch error and show alert
    alert('Geo Location failed.');
}).finally (function () { // remove loader
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```